# INFO: Scanning in Azcopy taking too much time

Tags: azure, azcopy

I did an Azcopy command

```
azcopy copy "C:\local\path" "https://account.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer1/?sv=2018-03-28&ss=bjqt&srt=sco&sp=rwddgcup&se=2019-05-01T05:01:17Z&st=2019-04-30T21:01:17Z&spr=https&sig=MGCXiyEzbtttkr3ewJIh2AR8KrghSy1DGM9ovN734bQF4%3D" --recursive=true
```

But it shows "INFO: Scanning.." for a long time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"INFO: Scanning" is a standard message for almost all errors that can happen. This has got many people confused into thinking some sort of scanning is going on and that we need to wait. But actually it could be some other simple error like incorrect blob name or container name as was in my case.

EDIT: to learn about the actual error and location check the answer in this page from Gpack.

Answer (score 2):

I got stuck too. To see if there are any errors, check out the logs created in the `%USERPROFILE%\.azcopy` directory on Windows or `$HOME/.azcopy` directory on Mac and Linux.

More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-configure